# Получение миллисекунд от дат из массива JS

Tags: javascript, массивы

Я только начинаю изучать JS. Что с моим кодом не так?

```
let date=["2019-09-09","2019-07-09","2019-10-09","2019-11-09"];

function realTime(){    
    for(let i=0;i<date.length;i++);    
    date.getTime(i);    
}
```

Comment: Читать про new Date(), массивы, типы данных и области видимости.. В коде всё не так.

Comment: про циклы еще..

Comment: перефразируйте вопрос, чтобы он был понятен и отражал то., что Вы хотите получить

Comment: вы пытаетесь получить время у массива, а не у элемента массива, поэтому не работает

Answer (score 0):

```
let date=["2019-09-09","2019-07-09","2019-10-09","2019-11-09"];

function realTime(){    
    for(const i of date);    
    date.getTime(i);    
}
```

У тебя в i был просто индекс а не элемент по индексу,
посмотри как работают циклы for, for of, for in, и в чем их отличия

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: hint: в форме редактирования сообщения, в её верхнем правом углу, есть картинка в виде вопросительного знака внутри кружочка. если его нажать, появится панель с разделами подсказок. среди них есть, например, «код». попробуйте нажать на это слово и почитать подсказку.

Answer (score 0):

```
let date=["2019-09-09","2019-07-09","2019-10-09","2019-11-09"];
function realTime(){    
    for(let i=0;i<date.length;i++);    
    date.getTime(i);    
}
```

Заменить на:

```
let date=["2019-09-09","2019-07-09","2019-10-09","2019-11-09"];
function realTime(){    
    for(let i=0;i<date.length;i++);    
    date.getTime(date[i]);    
}
```

Поскольку, как указано в ответе выше (

> в i был просто индекс а не элемент по индексу, посмотри как работают циклы for, for of, for in, и в чем их отличия

), в цикле под значение i подставляется числовое порядковое значение элемента массива, а не сам элемент массива. Чтобы исправить, измените getTime(i) на getTime(date[i]).